# Bootstrap Mobile Navbar Toggle Button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, navbar

Just wondering if there was a way to move the navbar-toggle button http://prntscr.com/5sldgb further down inside the navbar after changing the navbars height.

HTML

```
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <img class="navbar-brand" src="assets/images/logo.png"/>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li><a href="#index">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Example">Example</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#team">Our Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Example">Example</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#enquire">Enquire Now</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Example">Example</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div><!--/.navbar -->
```

CSS can be found in the JS Fiddle.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/24duac9g/

Thanks!

Comment: if you want to just move the toggle button in the navbar below, change the margin-top:8px to anything higher that is mentioned in navbar-toggle class.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the `margin-top` of `.navbar-toggle`

```
.navbar-toggle{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 50px
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/24duac9g/1/)